# Conditionally use STUN server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, asterisk, stun

Let's assume we are using Asterisk with WebRTC enabled. When we are trying to establish a connection between two hosts on different networks we need to use
STUN server to correctly determine their public addresses in case they are behind NAT. But whenever the two ends of the connection reside on the same network we don't need to resort to STUN server. So the question is if there is a possibility to determine somehow if the clients are on the same network or not?

Comment: Actually, using a STUN server is a great way to find out if two clients are on the same network, but since using STUN is what you want to avoid, then no. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not reliably.

But it doesn't matter.  STUN is cheap and fast. It only echoes back what your publicly visible IP:port address is.  When WebRTC negotiates a connection, all the discovered addresses (local and stun mapped) are used.

If two nodes are on the same private LAN, the algorithm that WebRTC uses will converge to using the private IP addresses of the two nodes instead of the mapped addresses obtained from STUN.  When connecting through STUN, the connection is still direct instead of relayed.

Similarly, if you are also using TURN relays, WebRTC (and any ICE like protocol) will default to private and STUN addresses before falling back to TURN.